# JAVA : regarding System.out

Tags: java

JAVA : is there a difference between the two references "p" && "pp"?

```
    PrintStream p = new PrintStream(System.out);
    p.println("lol");

    PrintStream pp = System.out;
    pp.println("lol");
```

I would just like to shorten the System.out.println(); statement for some prototyping.
cheers! matt

Comment: Shorten it. If it pleases you, you can even `import static System.out`. You'll get even shorter, and more readable, code if you declare a method `public static void p(String s) { System.out.println(x); }`

Comment: Not sure p("blah"); is more readable than out.println("blah"); Maybe print("blah") would be.

Comment: @mik It gets readable the first time you use F3 and find out what `p` is up to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no behavioral difference between the two.

`System.out` is already a `PrintStream`, and a `new PrintStream(otherPrintStream)` just creates a wrapper object which only delegates to the given `PrintStream`.

---

As @MarkoTopolnik suggest, you can even do

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

and just do

```
out.println("lol");
```

if you want to keep it short.

Answer (score 3):

There is no functional difference, although the first creates a new object that you don't need and is therefore slightly less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

No difference.

Both the statement will effect the same. Slightly difference is we are creating a new object of PrintStream class in first statement unnecessary.